# Foreign keys integrity issue

Tags: database, foreign-keys

I am having issues regarding the following relations. First image depicts the issue.Second image depicts my solution but still undesirable.How can I satisfy my business rule here.Does this rule has to be avoided using safe code or am I missing something here in this model.

**MAIN ISSUE**
[image]

**NAIVE SOLUTION**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, to achieve you business rule, make the employee id primary and add UNIQUE constraint for username field.